# Duas versões de python no Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

Eu acho que tem algo de errado no meu pc. Ele mostra que tanto o python 3.5.2 quanto o 2.7.12 estão como default. Como corrige isso?

E eu fui tentar atualizar a versão do Ubuntu da 16.04 pra 18.04 e me apareceu uma msg falando que não é possível a atualização pq o meu python 3 está corrompido, imagino que seja por causa desse problema que descrevi?

Alguém sabe o que eu devo fazer?
Obrigada

Comment: normal ter py2 e py3 instalados, infelizmente não sei como auxiliar para corrigir o py3, curiosamente ontem fui atualizar para o mint20 e tambem tive um erro, no final resolvi fazer uma instalação nova

Answer (score 0):

Tente definir o Python padrão como o **3.5** utilizando o comando:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

Se isso não funcionar, você pode reinstalar os pacotes do `python3` utilizando o comando:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
```

Se ainda assim não funcionar, remova todos os pacotes `python` do `update-alternatives` e defina o Python **2.7** como padrão utilizando os comandos:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```